# How to install Auctex

Tags: auctex, latex, package

This is how I attempted to install the package:

I ran the command `list-packages` and then tried to install the `auctex` package in package mode. This was the line showing `auctex` entry in package mode:

```
  auctex             11.88.2      available  gnu        Integrated environment for *TeX*
```

Now when I try to install that, I get this message:

> package--check-signature: Failed to verify signature
>   auctex-11.88.2.tar.sig: ("Bad signature from 474F05837FBDEF9B GNU ELPA
>   Signing Agent ")

How do I fix this ? Any other method to install `auctex` is also welcome.

Comment: In addition to ELPA and source code, you can also install it via your OS's package manager if possible.

Comment: When I have trouble installing from `list-packages`, the first thing I try is to start emacs fresh with a minimal version of my init file. Sometimes there are conflicts with active packages... but I have no idea if that's what this error could be from.

Comment: That looks like a serious problem that should be reported via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Do you have the following line in your `.emacs`? (setq-default coding-system-for-read 'utf-8) If so, try removing it, restarting emacs and installing the package. It seems there is some problem with gnupg, package.el and emacs when coding system is set to utf8.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, please report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, because it *really* should not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just installed it from source:

1. get the source code: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download.html
2. build:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.emacs.d/site-lisp/auctex --with-lispdir=$HOME/.emacs.d/site-lisp/auctex --with-texmf-dir=$HOME/.local/lib/texmf
   make
   make install
   ```

   (this builds auctex for a user and doesn't require superuser privilages)
3. load to emacs:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/auctex")
   (load "auctex.el" nil t t)
   (load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
   ```

That's it: calling `M-x latex-mode` then loads auctex.

Comment: Thanks, just curious to know if package-mode method worked for you ?

Comment: Last time I had been installing auctex (about 2 years ago) it has been working. In that time I used package-install specially to test the system. Currently I'm not using package-install and prefer to install el libraries from source.

Answer (score 1):

On a Debian-based linux system I used

```
sudo apt-get install auctex
```

at the command prompt in a terminal and that did the necessary. This should work on Ubuntu and other Debian based linux systems.

Of course, I had previously used

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

I know that this is a late answer, but here just in case it might help someone else