# Installing Auctex from Package Manager: Scan error

Tags: package, latex, auctex

When install `auctex` from the Package manager using GNU Archive, I get this error:

```
forward-sexp: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 18984, 38451
```

This always happens to me when I install it using the package manager. If I instead install it [manually](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10048/904) then everything works. Is there a way to solve the above error ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by GNU Archive. I just installed it from elpa, and it installed without a hitch. You might try to turn on debugging (`M-x set-variable RET debug-on-error RET t RET`) and see if you can learn anything from the backtrace. Failing that, please give us an exact description of the steps you are following to install the package.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Instead of repository Like MELPA, I'm using this archive: "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" for installing auctex. That's what I meant by GNU Archive. This is the entire log message from the *Messages* buffer [during installing](https://gist.github.com/psibi/0012ec8341a2a849dc86)

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of what you are saying. The page you are pointing at (http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/) *is* a repository “like MELPA”, except it is ELPA, like I said. If you are fetching the archive from there to install it, it seems to me that you *are* installing it manually, yet you say that manual installation works, while whatever it is you're doing does not work. Once again, what exactly did you do to get this error?

Comment: To be precise, I think the best way to install packages from (M)ELPA is to [follow the instructions](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) on the Emacs wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the coding system set to a fixed value.  E.g. by using

```
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
```

in your .emacs file.  Setting this variable overrides the settings for individual files and lines like `-*- coding: iso-2022-jp-unix; -*-` get ignored.  In my installation this skrewed up the generation of the autoloads for auctex during installation and resulted in the same scan error.

Test if this problem applies to you: locate were the elpa archives are extracted and open then file elpa/auctex-11.89/tex-jp.el.  If `buffer-buffer-file-coding-system` is not set to `iso-2022-jp-unix`, then this is the problem.

The solution is to *not* set `coding-system-for-read` globally.  See http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_encoding_decoding_faq.html for how to set the default coding system properly.

Comment: Wow, you figured out the root cause of the problem. That's the exact thing I was getting hit with.