# AUCTeX error "Symbol’s function definition is void: texmathp"

Tags: auctex

From time to time I am having trouble using auctex properly. That means, after typing-in `C-c C-f C-e` I receive the following error message:

`Symbol’s function definition is void: texmathp`

Sometimes I am also unable to type in a minus symbol `-`, same error message.

I have installed `auctex-12.1.1` via elpa (on a Windows machine, for more information see below).

I used to have something like

```
(require 'tex-site)
(require 'tex-mik)
```

in my `init.el` (see below).

The strange thing is, everything works without `(require 'tex-mik)` but then I am unable to use `C-c C-f C-e` (includes an `\emph{}`) or `C-c C-e`, which I really depend on.

Any ideas what is going on?

**My emacs version**

```
In GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2017-09-12 built on KAEL
Windowing system distributor 'Microsoft Corp.', version 6.1.7601
Configured using:
 'configure --prefix=/tmp/emacs --without-imagemagick --without-dbus
 --with-modules 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g0''
```

**My init.el (hopefully a MWE)**

```
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
             ("elpy" . "https://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/")
             ))

(setq package-check-signature nil)



(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")  

(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))   

(package-initialize)

(require 'tex-site)
(require 'tex-mik)
```

Comment: Can you please remove `(require 'tex-site) (require 'tex-mik)` from your init file, restart Emacs and then remove and re-install AUCTeX from ELPA?

Comment: Thanks, @ArashEsbati ! Id did that, however, as I mentioned in my question, then essential AUCTeX features (e.g., `C-c C-e`) no longer work. During the installation process, I also got the following error: `autoload-generate-file-autoloads: tex-jp.el:0:0: error: scan-error: (Unbalanced parentheses 24404 44141)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think that I found the error:

1. Searching for the `autoload-generate-file-autoloads:...` error (see my comment under my question) lead to another question on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18467/168 that provided a solution on how to properly set the encoding system (["How to permanently choose a encoding system in emacs for opening and saving?"](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_encoding_decoding_faq.html)).
2. So, in my init.el, I removed all utf8-related lines and added just one line

`(set-language-environment "UTF-8")`

3. Then, I removed AUCTeX again, reinstalled it again, and now, everything works like a charm.